# unable to run gatbsy site locally with docker-compose

Tags: node.js, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, gatsby

This is my first time using `docker` and I have downloaded a `docker-compose.yml` from https://github.com/wodby/docker4wordpress which is a repo with docker images for `wordpress` . I am planning to use `wordpress` as a backend and use created blog posts  from it's API in  a `Gatsby` site . My problem is that since I don't have experience with docker I am unable to
run my gatsby site locally using the `node` image the above link provides inside my `docker-compose.yml` . I can run wordpress succesfully however as I had help from my boss to configure the above file before trying to use gatsby and node .

My project structure :

```
Wordpress_Project
 |
 +-- numerous wordpress folders  
 |    
 +-- gatsby_site folder 
 |    
 +-- docker-compose.yml
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    volumes:
#    - ./mariadb-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init .sql file(s) here.
    - bedrock_dbdata:/var/lib/mysql # I want to manage volumes manually.

  php:
    image: wodby/wordpress-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_php"
    environment:
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: $DB_HOST
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      PHP_FPM_USER: www-data
      PHP_FPM_GROUP: www-data
#      # Read instructions at https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/wordpress/local#xdebug
#      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
#      PHP_XDEBUG_MODE: debug
#      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=my-ide
#      PHP_XDEBUG_IDEKEY: "my-ide"
#      PHP_XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST: 172.17.0.1 # Linux
#      PHP_XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST: host.docker.internal # Docker 18.03+ Mac/Win
#      PHP_XDEBUG_CLIENT_HOST: 10.0.75.1 # Windows
#      PHP_XDEBUG_LOG: /tmp/php-xdebug.log
    volumes:
    - ./:${CODEBASE}:cached
## Alternative for macOS users: Mutagen https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/wordpress/local#docker-for-mac
#    - mutagen:/var/www/html
#    # For XHProf and Xdebug profiler traces
#    - files:/mnt/files

  crond:
    image: wodby/wordpress-php:$PHP_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_crond"
    environment:
      CRONTAB: "0 * * * * wp cron event run --due-now --path=${CODEBASE}/web/wp"
    command: sudo -E LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so crond -f -d 0
    volumes:
      - ./:${CODEBASE}:cached


  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog"
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.loadbalancer.server.port=8025"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_mailhog.rule=Host(`mailhog.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"

  nginx:
    image: wodby/nginx:$NGINX_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx"
    depends_on:
    - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_VHOST_PRESET: wordpress
      NGINX_SERVER_NAME: ${PROJECT_BASE_URL}
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: ${CODEBASE}/web
    volumes:
    - ./:${CODEBASE}:cached
## Alternative for macOS users: Mutagen https://wodby.com/docs/stacks/wordpress/local#docker-for-mac
#    - mutagen:/var/www/html
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_nginx.rule=Host(`${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"


  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer"
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"


  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
    - '80:80'
  #    - '8080:8080' # Dashboard
    volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

#this is the node image where I want to run gatsby locally 
  node:
    image: wodby/node:$NODE_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_node"
    working_dir: /app
    labels:
    - "traefik.http.services.${PROJECT_NAME}_node.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
    - "traefik.http.routers.${PROJECT_NAME}_node.rule=Host(`node.${PROJECT_BASE_URL}`)"
    expose:
    - "3000"
    volumes:
    - ./gatsby_site:/app
    command: sh -c 'npm install && npm run start'


volumes:
  bedrock_dbdata:
    external: true
```

I am trying to configure the above node image but I am unsuccessfull so far . I try accessing the node url on localhost only to get error 404 .

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: This is a pretty advanced setup, are you sure you need both Nginx and Traefik, email service and all in order to use Wordpress as a headless CMS? I would say there's too much you probably don't need here. I would also try this without any environment variables first, just to avoid "dumb" errors with those.